# Variadic templated type as return type, MSVC weirdness

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, variadic

Given the following code:

```
class DummyOK {
   public:
    template <typename U, typename... Args>
    class AThing {
       public:
    };

   public:
    template <typename U, typename... Args>
    AThing<U, Args...> GetAThing();
};

template <typename U, typename... Args>
typename DummyOK::template AThing<U, Args...> DummyOK::GetAThing() {
    return AThing<U, Args...>{};
}

template <typename T>
class DummyKO {
   public:
    template <typename U, typename... Args>
    class AThing {
       public:
    };

   public:
    template <typename U, typename... Args>
    AThing<U, Args...> GetAThing();

    template <typename U, typename... Args>
    AThing<U, Args...> AnOtherGetAThing() {
        return AThing<U, Args...>{};
    }
};

template <typename T>
template <typename U, typename... Args>
typename DummyKO<T>::template AThing<U, Args...> DummyKO<T>::GetAThing() {
    return AThing<U, Args...>{};
}

int main() {
    DummyOK{}.GetAThing<char, unsigned, float>();
    DummyKO<int>{}.GetAThing<char, unsigned, float>();
    DummyKO<int>{}.AnOtherGetAThing<char, unsigned, float>();

    return 0;
}
```

Also available here: https://godbolt.org/z/8747rj77K

Why does it compiles on clang/gcc but not msvc.
Why does AnOtherGetAThing() compiles but not GetAThing() (on msvc).

The error returned by msvc is:

```
<source>(39): error C2244: 'DummyKO<T>::GetAThing': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
<source>(39): note: see declaration of 'DummyKO<T>::GetAThing'
<source>(39): note: definition
<source>(39): note: 'DummyKO<T>::AThing<U,Args...> DummyKO<T>::GetAThing(void)'
<source>(39): note: existing declarations
<source>(39): note: 'DummyKO<T>::AThing<U,Args...> DummyKO<T>::GetAThing(void)'
```

Thanks

Comment: With this version: https://godbolt.org/z/W66nvfG15 clang complains :/

Comment: But msvc compiles..

Comment: @EtienneM: Which MSVC version? In the past, MSVC had issues with two-phase name lookup.

Comment: @MSalters his example failed on latest MSVC: https://godbolt.org/z/zWj85s8cG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say msvc bug,

as workaround, you might use trailing return type:

```
template <typename T>
template <typename U, typename... Args>
auto DummyKO<T>::GetAThing() -> AThing<U, Args...>
{
    // ...
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/f1WMdod5x)

Comment: I think it's a bug too.
I tried using auto+trailing return type like that:
```template <typename T>
template <typename U, typename... Args>
auto DummyKO<T>::GetAThing() -> typename DummyKO<T>::template AThing<U, Args...> {
    return AThing<U, Args...>{};
}```
Note that I used typename and ::template. Using that syntax, the msvc quirk shows itself again.
My question is then:
Why is your syntax (without typename/template) valid c++, and if it is why am I required to write typename/template when I do not use the trailing return type.

Comment: Before `DummyKO<T>::GetAThing`, you are in global/namespace scope, and not class scope, so you would need to a the inner type (which is dependent, so `typename`/`template` usage). After, we are in class scope, so no need to prepend with class name; but if we do, inner class would be dependent again.